# Clean URL link for page without number

Tags: pages, urls

This is probably a really noob question, but I can't figure out how to change it.  I've created a page called "Photos" and my url link shows:

```
http://mysite.com/photo-7/
```

What's with the **-7** and how do I remove this so it is just *photo*?

Comment: do you have other pages in the trash with a similar permalink?

Comment: @Milo Yes I had some in the trash from previous pages that I created.  I though when you moved them to trash, that it deleted them, but was not the case. I found where you can delete them permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your site already has a post or page (6 in your case) with the slug "photo."

They might be in the trash, or pending as drafts, or whatever ... but WordPress automatically appends number to prevent name conflicts.

So go through your site, and figure out which other pages are trying to use the "photo" slug and change their slug to something else.  Then you can re-edit your other page to change its slug to just `photo` rather than `photo-7`.